# IE10 sending image button click coordinates with decimals (floating point values) causing a ParseInt32 FormatException

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

It seems like ASP.NET 4.0 is not prepared to handle ImageButton events triggered by Internet Explorer 10. The problem is that IE10 sends the image click coordinates as double values (with decimals), and ASP.NET tries to parse them as integers, presenting the following type of error:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): 
   Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. 
   ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.members_addtocartlogin_twostep_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\932deaba\63ff7eeb\App_Web_MyPage.aspx.28424a96.oraym_un.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Googling around, some people suggest forcing IE10 to run in compatibility view. However, adding the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />` does not solve anything; and adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">` before `<!DOCTYPE>` doesn't work either.

Any solutions? Could I capture the click event with Javascript and remove the decimals somehow?

**Note:** Upgrading to Framework 4.5 and recompiling fixes the bug. No need to change the runtime version, since it's still 4.0.

Comment: See also the related [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not)

Comment: We ended up upgrading to Framework 4.5. The application pool's runtime version is still 4.0, but the upgrade fixes the bug.

Comment: The fastest temporary fix untill Microsoft updates the frmaework is to add this in your masterpages header: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Comment: An option is to use an asp:Button and style it with a background image. (Set background color, width, height, border, etc to remove the button appearance.) Not a general solution, but if you only have one or two of these may be the simplest one.

Comment: Microsoft shouldn't fix .NET, they should fix IE 10. The click coordinates should be integers according to both HTML 5 and HTML 4.01 (and I really really can't think of a reason to want anything else).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Simply installing .NET Framework 4.5 can fix this problem.**

This can fix the problem even if you do not switch your application pool over to .NET Framework 4.5.

In my case, I left the app pools at .NET Framework 3.5. Apparently installing .NET Framework 4.5 overwrites some files for other framework versions.

Since it is so easy to install the new .NET Framework version, it's probably worth a try before bothering with the hotfixes (which did not work for me) or other solutions.

See the workarounds section [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not)

Answer (score 22):

There are hotfixes for .NET CLR 2.0 and 4.0, as described in [this blog entry by Scott Hanselmann](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx):

> What the fixes do is update the ie.browser and firefox.browser files
>   in `\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\Config\Browsers` with new
>   and future-proofed versions of these browser definitions. Nothing else
>   is affected.

.NET 4

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

.NET 2.0

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100 for Win7 SP1/Windows
  Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Vista/Server 2008, Windows XP/Server 2003
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565 for Win7/Windows Server
  2008 R2 RTM

Alternatively, there's a client-based javascript patch (originally posted as workaround on the [Connect item with bug ID:755419](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not)):

```
$(function () {
    // Patch fractional .x, .y form parameters for IE10.
    if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined' && Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer && Sys.Browser.version === 10) {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormElementActive = function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormElementActive(element, offsetX, offsetY) {
            if (element.disabled) {
                return;
            }
            this._activeElement = element;
            this._postBackSettings = this._getPostBackSettings(element, element.name);
            if (element.name) {
                var tagName = element.tagName.toUpperCase();
                if (tagName === 'INPUT') {
                    var type = element.type;
                    if (type === 'submit') {
                        this._additionalInput = encodeURIComponent(element.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(element.value);
                    }
                    else if (type === 'image') {
                        this._additionalInput = encodeURIComponent(element.name) + '.x=' + Math.floor(offsetX) + '&' + encodeURIComponent(element.name) + '.y=' + Math.floor(offsetY);
                    }
                }
                else if ((tagName === 'BUTTON') && (element.name.length !== 0) && (element.type === 'submit')) {
                    this._additionalInput = encodeURIComponent(element.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(element.value);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Ding, ding ding. We have a winner. I am running .Net 4.0 on a 2003 server and the hot fix 2600088 did not work for me. I didn't want to install 4.5, but the client script is working for me.

Comment: this script works like a charm. This should be accepted answer !

Comment: Thanks for the script. I was working on a site where I didn't have control enough to update the framework or install hotfixes. This script saved a lot of headaches.

Comment: Where should I use the script ?

Comment: I mean where should I copy paste the javascript code since I use many pages in my website and almost every page has image buttons

Comment: Don't Copy & Paste; include it as a file in a MasterPage, which you then use for your site.

Comment: Script verification condition should be updated to `Sys.Browser.version >= 10` since now, we also have IE 11....

Comment: @NunoAgapito I've tried this, but IE11 doesn't identify itself in the same way (i.e. its user agent is *very* different) so that doesn't work!

Comment: I LOVE U....love this javascript solution. it solve the war between the server technician and the developer in my department. MUUUACCHH...THis is the best answer for me. in the future i will advise the server technician to upgrade their .net framework. Good luck, and thanks again. VOTE UP.

Comment: I requested for .NET 4 hotfix, however the download link in email is broken and gives error 404 file not found. Whom should I contact to get correct link?

Comment: The download links are fine (just tried it), just click on it. Here are they again.

x86:
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%204.0%20-%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%202003,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Win7,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20(MSI)/nosp/DevDiv953277/30319.504/free/436906_intl_i386_zip.exe

x64:
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%204.0%20-%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%202003,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Win7,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20(MSI)/nosp/DevDiv953277/30319.504/free/436907_intl_x64_zip.exe

Comment: It actually doesn't work with IE 11: The browser-detection fails, because Sys.Browser.agent is null

Answer (score 7):

Here's a JavaScript workaround. It overrides the existing method, floors the x and y coordinates then calls the existing method with these new coordinates.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._origOnFormActiveElement = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormElementActive;
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormElementActive = function(element, offsetX, offsetY){
    if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && element.type === 'image'){
        offsetX = Math.floor(offsetX);
        offsetY = Math.floor(offsetY);
    }
    this._origOnFormActiveElement(element, offsetX, offsetY);
};
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it is minimal inversive (still uses the original code). One important thing is missing though: It doesn't check for "Sys" and if it is executed twice, the browser will run into a stack-overflow. I added the following check around it: if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined' && typeof (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._origOnFormActiveElement) === 'undefined') {

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129393/1127114), this issue has been fixed in .NET 4.5.

For those who can't upgrade to .NET 4.5, Microsoft has released an update to fix this problem for .NET 4.0 ([KB2836939](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939)) and .NET 3.5 ([KB2836942](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836942) and [KB2836943](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836943)).

Here's how those KB articles describe the issue:

> When you click an ImageButton control that is inside an update panel on an ASP.NET-based webpage by using Internet Explorer 10 and later, the partial postback operation fails. Additionally, the server-side click event is not fired.

For reference, here's the original `ImageButton.LoadPostData` code that throws `FormatException`:

```
protected virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) {
    string name = UniqueID;
    string postX = postCollection[name + ".x"];
    string postY = postCollection[name + ".y"];
    if (postX != null && postY != null && postX.Length > 0 && postY.Length > 0) {
        x = Int32.Parse(postX, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        y = Int32.Parse(postY, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (Page != null) {
            Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's the fixed code:

```
protected virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) { 
    string name = UniqueID;
    string postX = postCollection[name + ".x"];
    string postY = postCollection[name + ".y"];
    if (postX != null && postY != null && postX.Length > 0 && postY.Length > 0) {
        x = (int)ReadPositionFromPost(postX);
        y = (int)ReadPositionFromPost(postY);
        if (Page != null) {
            Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

internal static double ReadPositionFromPost(string requestValue) {
    NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.Integer;
    return double.Parse(requestValue, style, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Variables x and y ?

Comment: @buffjape: This code was copied directly from the reference source. `x` and `y` are private `int` fields in `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

If you press F12 and switch to IE9 manually, it works like a charm. So our apporach was to use content="IE=9" but this only switches the document mode in IE10 not the browser mode and that seems to be not enough.

Maybe someone has an idea on how to switch the document mode too?

Another workaround that gets more and more popular is to overwrite LoadPostData, see

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/496162/IE10-and-ImageButtons?display=Mobile
http://forums.asp.net/t/1823287.aspx/2/10

Personally I woulve have found the content="IE=9" the best solution because of the little additional work and impact.

Comment: Just to clarify about overriding. Presumably I would need to create my own control subclassing ImageButton and then replace all ImageButtons in my application with the new class?

Answer (score 0):

Actually is a different issue than the ones listed by tkrause.  There is a hotfix available, although I can't figure out how to apply it.  Here is info for those that do know how to apply these:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784147

If you check the ASP.NET section is has the exact error stated in this question.  This is the exact error and issue I am having also.

I think I cannot get the update because I'm using Server 2003.  I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 and VS 2008, so upgrading to 4.x isn't an easy option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sub-classing the ImageButton, and correcting the data before it was passed in for processing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Xception.WebControls
{
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal),
    AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal),
    DefaultEvent("Click"),
    ToolboxData("<{0}:ImageButton runat=\"server\"> </{0}:ImageButton>")]
    public class ImageButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton
    {
        protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
        {
            NameValueCollection newCollection = new NameValueCollection();

            foreach (string key in postCollection.AllKeys)
            {
                if (key.Equals(this.UniqueID + ".x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    newCollection[this.UniqueID + ".x"] = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(postCollection[this.UniqueID + ".x"])).ToString();
                else if (key.Equals(this.UniqueID + ".y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    newCollection[this.UniqueID + ".y"] = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(postCollection[this.UniqueID + ".y"])).ToString();
                else
                    newCollection[key] = postCollection[key];
            }

            return base.LoadPostData(postDataKey, newCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in the header of each page or the master page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

This will force IE10 into IE9 standards document mode, and it can handle image postbacks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am not currently able to upgrade .Net to 4.5 and I didn't want to use JavaScript to patch the bug.

The solution that I went with was to convert my ImageButton to a LinkButton:

This was my ImageButton:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="MyButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="my tooltip" ImageUrl="../Images/button.gif" OnClick="MyButton_Click" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

This is the LinkButton I replaced it with:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="MyButton_Click">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/button.gif" alt="my tooltip"/>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

From the user's perspective, it all works the same as it did before....but without the crashing in IE.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, on the master page we added below line of code under `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

This worked for us as it allows the page to be rendered in the version of IE that is specified.