# SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, authentication, client-side, internet-explorer-10

On IE10, when I click the login button I see the following error in the console:
SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format. 
ScriptResource.axd, line 939 character 13

I added some server-side logging, but the page is never sent, so it seems a client side issue.

This behavior does not occur in IE8, Firefox OR chrome, there it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is occurring because your submit button is an `input` with `type="image"`. Therefore, coordinates are submitted with the form. Previous versions of Internet Explorer submit those coordinates as integers, but Internet Explorer 10 submits them as decimals.

There are a variety of ways to fix it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13299685/937084) and [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not) for some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with ie 10. Simply upgrade net framework to 4.5. This will solve your issue.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have undergone the same problem, My Configurations settings are as follows,

Application running on framework 3.5,

IIS application pool framework version v2.0,

Internet Explorer 10..

Please Set the IE in compatibility View then all errors gone away for me. If still someone searching for the same problem please you could give it a try by setting the IE in compatibility mode for that website....