# Input string was not in a correct format.

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

this error is shown IE10

SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format.

am using

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="CalculateDriveAwayPriceImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/show-prices.gif" />
```

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265886/script5022-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-input-string-wa

Comment: There is no solution useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using update panel than this type of Exception generated on page postback becoz of some error

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Comment: Have any solution regarding this.

Comment: you have to debug code and find error ..it is also possible that error in aspx control on your aspx page