# Gridview Image Button RowCommand not working in IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have Image button in gridview item template. When click on that image in RowCommand event `CommandName` is showing different then what I am expecting. It always says "Select", But I am  expecting "pdf".

This is only happening in IE. Not Chrome.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdLoan" Width="100%" runat="server" CssClass="grid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader"
                PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-CssClass="gridItem" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridAltItem"
                AllowPaging="false" BackColor="LightGray">
                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Loan Number" DataField="strAltLoanNumber">
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Security" DataField="strGlobalSecurity">
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sample #" DataField="intSampleID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PDF">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton CommandName="pdf" ID="imgPDF" ImageUrl="~/Images/pdf.png" runat="server"
                                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("strGlobalLoanNumber")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

### Gridview Events

```
Private Sub grdLoan_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdLoan.RowCreated

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';"
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.grdLoan, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub  

  Private Sub grdLoan_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdLoan.RowCommand
        If e.CommandName = "pdf" Then
        end if
End sub
```

Even I tried

```
<asp:ImageButton CommandName="pdf" ID="imgPDF" ImageUrl="~/Images/pdf.png"
 runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("strNumber")%>' OnClick="imgPDF_Click" />
```

Onclick event never fires and Chrome its working.

Also tried

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton ...>
```

First time `RowCommand` firing twice. once `Edit` and another one is `select`.  If I click second time it is `Select`.

I don't understand whats going on.

Comment: Have you tried my answer about 'Page_Load'?

Answer (score 1):

i check your code but it's working here i am using IE 8 and its working in it.

what i changed:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLoan" Width="100%" runat="server" CssClass="grid" HeaderStyle-   CssClass="gridHeader" PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
 RowStyle-CssClass="gridItem" **onRowCommand = "grdLoan_RowCommand"** AlternatingRowStyle- CssClass="gridAltItem" AllowPaging="false" BackColor="LightGray">
```

and in code page

```
protected void grdLoan_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "pdf")
        {
        }
    }
```

i am getting commandname properly in IE 8...

Comment: he uses `Handles grdLoan.RowCreated` instead of an attribute-declaration

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't see that you have an ID.

I think you're using the IE 10.

There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

**Simply installing .NET Framework 4.5 can fix this problem.**

This can fix the problem even if you do not switch your application pool over to .NET Framework 4.5.

Related: [ImageButton does not fire a post back on IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330468/imagebutton-does-not-fire-a-post-back-on-ie10)

Comment: Could you please show the first line of you GridView?

Comment: You've missed `OnRowCreated="grdLoan_RowCreated" OnRowCommand="grdLoan_RowCommand"`

Comment: err:'grdLoan_RowCommand' is not a member of 'ASP.home_aspx'. i dont think it needs because I am handling in the code behind with `Handles grdLoan.RowCreated`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Page_Load method and **ensure** that you bind your grid inside the IsPostback check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) // Don't forget this
    {
        grdLoan.DataSource = ...;
        grdLoan.DataBind();
    }
}
```