# Image Buttons click are not working in IE 11 while clicking on it in c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, buttonclick

Image Button Click is working sometimes. sometimes notihng is happening when i click on it.
I have given two image buttons in gridview.
Im using .Net Framework 4.5
getting error in  __doPostBack('Download_Click','') only in IE 11

Aspx code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="gridbtndownload" ToolTip="Download" CommandName="Download"
 OnClientClick="link();"  CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'
 runat="server" ImageUrl="Download_Icon.png" alt="Download" />
```

cs code

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(mypath); folder.Delete(true);
```

Comment: Do you see an JavaScript error?

Comment: When you hover over the Imagebutton see at the lower left side of the screen for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Press F12. On the left click Console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageButton does not fire a post back on IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330468/imagebutton-does-not-fire-a-post-back-on-ie10)

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known IE 10/11 bug, which requires you to upgrade .NET Framework and ASP.NET to workaround,

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not

Try to follow the direction if your call stack matches it.

Make sure that next time you post as much information as possible so that others can help you out. When you type too little, your question will be voted to close.