# Finding where Input string was not in a correct format is occuring

Tags: c#, exception

We have a web application with error handling in the global.asax file that goes through any uncaught exception and emails us with the details which include the exception stack trace and the inner exception (if there is one) stack trace.  This usually works very well giving us the class name, page name and line number of where the error started.  In one page's case we're not getting anything more than the error below.  So, I don't know if it's happening when the page loads, when the user posts back, when it calls the controller sending the object to the database or somewhere else.  Can anyone suggest a way to track this specific error down to a line number?  Thanks.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Have you checked for the InnerException?

Comment: Yes.  The exception handling code looks for an inner exception and if not null, reports all of the data from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE10 sending image button click coordinates with decimals (floating point values) causing a ParseInt32 FormatException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299685/ie10-sending-image-button-click-coordinates-with-decimals-floating-point-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page
http://forums.asp.net/t/1823287.aspx/1 describes a similar problem that seems to be related to IE10 and image buttons.  The suggestion is that IE10 is sending the click coordinates as decimals rather than integers, but the .Net framework code is parsing using ParseInt32 as shown in your stack trace.  Updating your .Net framework on the server may help.

Comment: I did notice that at the very bottom of the reported form fields that were submitted I have exactly what you're describing.  btnAddStates.x - 24.15999984741211 and btnAddStates.y - 54.28999710083008  So you think updating the framework will fix this?  Do you know what version it needs to be?

Comment: The page at [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not) has comments from some people saying that upgrading to .Net Framework 4.5 can help but YMMV.