# I have an error when I pull up a page from my web application but not my friend doesn't have that error when does

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2015, using the ASP.NET framework and I'm having problems. I can't fix my error and would like some help.

Front End:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="imgBtnSortTickets_Click" ID="imgBtnSortTickets" 
            runat="server" Text="Sort" SkinID="Buttons" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void imgBtnSortTickets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
```

I am working with source code and everything works fine until I add a button and add the onclick attribute. When I reference to my code behind the onclick will always get errors if it's to a new event click method. I even get this error when I reference to a javascript function. My friend however doesn't get this error when add new buttons. But when I try to run their code that they just added which worked on their end it won't work on mine. So basically If any new references are made to the code behind file using the onClick event I will receive an error even though I won't receive one on old ones? The following will be my error.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.triptickets_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'imgBtnSortTickets_Click' and no extension method 'imgBtnSortTickets_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.triptickets_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I fix this because neither myself or my friend know what's wrong since this exact button and event will work. I apologize if I didn't call something correctly because I'm an entry level developer.

Comment: Have you tried removing: `SkinID="Buttons"`?

Comment: check if that event is present in your code behind if it does exist, i would suggest close VS, open solution clean and rebuild

Comment: Can also check the `CausesValidation` property of your button, set it to `false` if it is `true`

Comment: @McNets that has nothing to do with the error I'm receiving.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I did try that and it didn't work but still thanks for the reply.

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby That didn't work. Keep in mind the exact same code works fine on my colleagues computer.

Comment: If it's not a big file, paste the whole .aspx text. I suppose it is not the only asp server control.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using IE10+ and your friend is using either IE 9 or below, or a non-IE browser.  IE changed the value passed in to a decimal for some reason, and that blows up on older versions of the .NET framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299685/ie10-sending-image-button-click-coordinates-with-decimals-floating-point-values/15129393#15129393

Comment: @ps2goat I am using Chrome for debugging purposes and he's using Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some of your autogenerated code got deleted somehow, and now your markup and your codebehind are out of sync.

You can fix this manually, but it's probably easier just to do it this way:

1. Edit the .aspx file in source code view and completely remove the markup for the button.
2. Access the .aspx page in designer view and add the button back by dragging a button from the toolkit.
3. Set the ID (and other properties) of the button using the Properties UI.
4. In the designer view, double click the button to autogenerate the scaffolding for the click event handler.
5. Edit the click event handler, being careful not to change its name or any part of its prototype.

If this fails, open your project in Visual Studio and do a global search of all files in the solution that contain "imgBtnSortTickets_Click".  Based on the error, you should find some markup that references it.  Whatever control is referencing it, delete the entire control, then recreate it using the designer.  If you are unsure how to edit the markup directly, edit your post and paste the code so we can help you.

Comment: Edited with further instructions